# How to insert a cover page in MS Word at the beginning of the document?

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, vsto, office-interop

I need to insert a cover page into a Word 2016 document.
The building block is a cover page and has

```
InsertOptions = (int)WdDocPartInsertOptions.wdInsertPage; //= 2
```

So far so good.

But VSTO can only insert so:

```
buildingBlock.Insert(range);
```

It does insert in place of range.

The event `Application.ActiveDocument.BuildingBlockInsert` is not raised.

Using native insert cover page (tab insert --> cover page) does insert properly (and creates only one undo entry insert building block).

```
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------
        // try 1
        var range = Application.ActiveDocument.Range();
        range.Collapse(WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart);
        buildingBlock.Insert(range);
        // result: inserting on the existing first page
        //           one undo entry 
        //           event BuildingBlockInsert has not been raised
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------
        // try 2
        //object start = 0;
        //object end = 0;
        //var range = Application.ActiveDocument.Range(ref start, ref end);
        //buildingBlock.Insert(range);
        // result: inserting on the existing first page
        //           one undo entry 
        //           event BuildingBlockInsert has not been raised
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------
        // try 3
        //var range = Application.ActiveDocument.Range();
        //range.InsertParagraphBefore();
        //var p = Application.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs[1];
        //buildingBlock.Insert(p.Range);
        // result: inserting on the existing first page
        //           two undo entries 
        //           event BuildingBlockInsert has not been raised
        // -----------------------------------------------------------------
```

A similar problem is described in Note of:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/word/concepts/working-with-word/working-with-building-blocks#inserting-a-building-block-into-a-document

It seems VSTO ignores any insert options, 
and there is no way to parameterize insert option by inserting.

How can VSTO insert a building block in a new first page as a Word native action?

I'm using VS 2017 Word 2016 Add-In, .Net Framework 4.6.1.

Comment: Please ask only one thing per question on Stack Overflow. If you're not familiar with this rule, please read up on asking questions in the site [help]. Please use the [edit] link to remove one of problems - you can ask it in a new question. For the event, please include relevant code (a [mcve]).

Comment: Try using the `Range.Collapse` method before using the range in `BuildingBlock.Insert`. Since you want it as the first page I recommend using `Word.WdCollapseDirection.wdCollapseStart` as the method argument.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, 
but range.Collapse disable only replacment of the range by futher inserting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Summary:

1. VSTO just "imitate" native Word building block inserting and not all features (InsertOptions) and functionalities (document event BuildingBlockInsert) are bound.
2. Combining native Word Ui user expirience (add/replace, remove cover page) and your custom VSTO Add-In (add/replace cover page) is only conditionally possible.

My current code:

```
private static Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application Application => Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;

private void InsertCoverPage(BuildingBlock buildingBlock)
{
    // validate not null
    if(buildingBlock == null) throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(buildingBlock));

    // validate is a cover page
    if (buildingBlock.Type.Index != (int)WdBuildingBlockTypes.wdTypeCoverPage &&
        buildingBlock.Type.Index != (int)WdBuildingBlockTypes.wdTypeCustomCoverPage)
    {
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(buildingBlock));
    }

    // validate insert option
    if (buildingBlock.InsertOptions != (int) WdDocPartInsertOptions.wdInsertPage) 
    {
        throw new Exception(
            "building block as a cover page must been inserted in a new page at the beginning of document");
    }

    Application.ScreenUpdating = false;

    Range range = GetCurrentCoverPageRange() ?? Application.ActiveDocument.Range(0, 0);// search a first existing cover page range

    range.InsertBreak(WdBreakType.wdPageBreak); // case existing cover page: replace by page break 
    // range.Start = 0; // = 0
    range.End = 0; // reset only end position
    buildingBlock.Insert(range, true);

    Marshal.ReleaseComObject(range);

    Application.ScreenUpdating = true;
}

private Range GetCurrentCoverPageRange()
{
    Range result = null;

    // Word insert natively a cover page with 2 paragraphs - so we need found these first 2 consecutive paragraphs marked as a cover page
    for (int i = 1; i < Application.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs.Count + 1; i++)
    {
        var paragraph = Application.ActiveDocument.Paragraphs[i];
        var isCoverPage = (bool)paragraph.Range.Information[WdInformation.wdInCoverPage];
        if (isCoverPage)
        {
            if (result == null)
            {
                result = paragraph.Range;
            }
            else
            {
                result.End = paragraph.Range.End;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (result != null)
            {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    return result;
}
```