# How can VSTO replace Word cover page?

Tags: c#, ms-word, interop, vsto, office-interop

I need to replace the existing cover page in Word by VSTO.

If you use native inserting, then Word replace existing cover page properly.

How can VSTO detect/retrieve the existing cover page?
VS 2017 Word Add-In, .Net 4.6.1.

Comment: See my reply to your question about inserting a Cover Page... DELETE all the content before the first page break in the document, then insert the other cover page.

Answer (score 0):

I have found:

```
var isCoverPage = (bool)range.Information[WdInformation.wdInCoverPage];
```

or so

```
var isCoverPage = (bool)paragraph.Range.Information[WdInformation.wdInCoverPage];
```

see an example on [my another thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53656061/how-to-insert-a-cover-page-in-ms-word-at-the-beginning-of-the-document/53743420#53743420)